# Using lists from another Site

Tags: list, cross-site, cross-list

On our company sharepoint we have a seperate Site per 'Department'.  I've been implementing a Contactperson list on our site, which has a link to one or more Hospitals (a seperate list on our site). However, it would be useful if I could use a 'global' list of Hospitals instead of each department having to define his own (identical) list of Hospitals to reference.

So, the question: how can I reference a List defined on another site in a list on my Site?

Comment: what's your company's portal topology looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the the BCS (Business Connectivity Services in SP2010) is an out of box feature enabling external business data to be shared between site collections without writing any code.

Here a link from microsoft
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx

and here an answer from Stackexchange:
[Sharing data between multiple site collections](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24971/sharing-data-between-multiple-site-collections)