# Cross site cross database lookup field SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, custom-field-types

SiteCollection 1 in ContentDB 1 has List 1 with custom lookup field.
This lookup field returns all text fields from any selected list in a site collection specified. Each site collection is in a different ContentDB.

Site Collection 2 in ContentDB 2 has List 2 with one item.

I am getting data from SiteCollection 2 correctly. 
I can view the data correctly.
However, i cant save the item.

I.E custom lookup field returns correct data but doesn't save. 
I am guessing its because I am trying to save an item from ContentDB 2 to ContentDB 1 and it doesnt exist in ContentDB1.

No errors or exceptions are thrown.

I havent had much luck on the net.

I have read that BCS would be able to solve my problem.
Is there any other way? How would using SPContentDatabase help me?

I can post code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is use the Business Connectivity Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819133.aspx

[Using lists from another Site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67445/using-lists-from-another-site/67448#67448)

it is the OOB way

Comment: I'm going to create the service. I will post details once im done. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I ended up creating the custom of type SPField. Everything works 100%. Thanks!